# Fluent NHibernate - Error with HasMany in new version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I Upgrade my NHibernate for 3.1.0.4000 and Fluent for 1.2.0.712 and have some problems with HasMany...

my entities:

```
public class MateriaPrima
{
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Product
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<ProductMateriaPrima> ListMateriaPrima { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public Product()
        {
            this.ListaMateriaPrima = new List<ProductMateriaPrima>();
        } 
}

public class ProductMateriaPrima
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product {get;set;}
    public virtual MateriaPrima MateriaPrima { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal PrecoCusto {get;set;}
}
```

And Maps:

```
public class MateriaPrimaMap : ClassMap<MateriaPrima>
{
    public MateriaPrimaMap()
    {
        Id(m => m.Id).Length(11).Not.Nullable();
        Map(m => m.Description).Length(90).Not.Nullable();
        Map(m => m.Date).Not.Nullable();
        Map(m => m.Price).Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class ProductMateriaPrimaMap : ClassMap<ProductoMateriaPrima>
    {
        public ProductMateriaPrimaMap()
        {
            Id(c => c.Id).Length(11);
            Map(c => c.Price).Not.Nullable();

            References(c => c.MateriaPrima).Column("IdMateriaPrima").Not.LazyLoad();
            References(c => c.Product).Column("IdProduct").Not.LazyLoad();
        }
    }

public class ProdutoMap : ClassMap<Produto>
    {
        public ProdutoMap()
        {
            Id(m => m.Id).Length(11).Not.Nullable();
            Map(m => m.Description).Length(90).Not.Nullable();
            Map(m => m.Price).Length(10);
            Map(m => m.Date).Length(12);
            Map(m => m.Active).Not.Nullable();

            HasMany(x => x.ListaMateriaPrima)
                    .Table("ProdutoMateriaPrima")
                    .KeyColumn("IdProduto")
                    .KeyColumn("IdMateriaPrima")
                    .Inverse()
                    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        }
    }
```

When i try to search, i got the error: {"Unknown column 'listamater0_.MateriaPrima_id' in 'field list'"}

This error don´t happen when i had the old version of Nhibernate and Fluent...
Someone know what´s happening?
Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

This error happend because you didn't set collumn name of Id property, default pattern for id is: entityname_id.
And now in ProductMateriaPrimaMap class you wrote:

```
References(c => c.MateriaPrima).Column("IdMateriaPrima")
```

This mean that in you MateriaPrimaMap class you should have Id with collumn name: IdMateriaPrima, but default you have name: MateriaPrima_Id.

I can't say where the problem is exactly because you didn't show the query. But i know that this error happend when Id column name is diffrent from Reference column name.